# Adding/Combining Standard Deviations

Tags: database, math, data-warehouse

**Short Version:**
Can StdDevs be added/combined? i.e.

```
if StdDev(11,14,16,17)=X and StdDev(21,34,43,12)=Y  
can we calculate StdDev(11,14,16,17,21,34,43,12) from X & Y
```

**Long Version:**
I am designing a star schema. The schema has a fact_table (grain=transaction) which stores individual transaction response_time. The schema also has an aggregate_table (grain=day) which stores the response_time_sum per day.
In my report I need to calculate standard deviations of the response time for a given timedimension, say day, week, month etc. How can I calculate the StandardDeviation using the aggregate_table instead of touching the huge fact_table?

Comment: I think the relationship between variances is `Var(X + Y) = Var(X) + Var(Y) + 2Cov(X, Y)`, so you need the covariance as well.

Comment: or a good estimate of the Covariance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, you can combine them. You need to know the number of observations, mean, and standard deviation for each day. The variance is easier to work with than the standard deviation, so I'll express everything else in terms of variance. (Standard deviation is defined as the square root of the variance.)

Denote:

```
n[i] # observations for day i
m[i] # mean for day i
v[i] # variance for day i
```

You'll need to calculate the total number of observations `N` and the overall mean `M`. This is easy:

```
days = [day1, day2, ..., day_final]
N = sum(n[i] for i in days)
M = sum(n[i] * m[i] for i in days) / N
```

The overall variance `V` is more complicated, but still can be calculated:

```
s1 = sum(n[i] * v[i] for i in days)
s2 = sum(n[i] * (m[i] - M)**2 for i in days)
V = (s1 + s2) / N
```

The above are for the population variance. If you instead have `v[i]` as the sample variance, some minor modifications to `s1` and `V` are needed:

```
s1_sample = sum((n[i] - 1) * v[i] for i in days)
V_sample = (s1_sample + s2) / (N - 1)
```

Comment: `Day_1 = (11,14,16,17), n = 4, m = 14.5, v = 7 |
Day_2 = (21,34,43,12), n = 4, m = 27.5, v = 188.33333 |
N = 8 | 
M = (4 * 14.5 + 4 * 27.5)/8 = 21 | 
S1 = ((4 * 7) + (4 * 188.33333)) = 781.33332 | 
S2 = ((4 * (14.5 - 21)^2) + (4 * (27.5 - 21)^2)) = 338 | 
V = (781.33332 + 338)/8 = 139.916665`

But Variance(11,14,16,17,21,34,43,12) = 132

Comment: The expressions I gave are for the population variance, the variances you're using are the sample variances. Presumably you have a lot of daily data, so you won't notice any difference in the results. If you think it likely to matter, there are analogous formulas for the sample variance.

Comment: First of all thanks for your inputs. Am using DB2 which has a VARIANCE function to calculate variance for a given set. But not sure if it is population or sample variance. Can you pls post the formulas for sample variance as well.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variance has both forms. It really just comes down to whether you divide the sum of the squared residuals by `n` for the population variance or `n-1` for the sample variance. My answer already has the equations needed for combining either the population or sample variance; note that the equations differ only in replacing `n[i]` by `n[i]-1`.

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't add standard deviations.

Prove it to yourself with the numbers you provided:

X = 2.645751311, Y = 13.72345923

Standard deviation of combined set: 11.48912529

You can do a more general proof using the formula for standard deviation.  You need the covariance of the two - scroll down to "identities":

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_deviation